# Parseval's equality for the Fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, integral-transforms, fourier-transform, piecewise-continuity

Please help me prove this!

f(x) is piecewise continuous on any interval, and $$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } |f(x)|dx < \infty$$

Here

$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[A(\alpha)\cos \alpha x + B (\alpha)\sin \alpha x]d \alpha$$

where

$$A(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \cos \alpha x dx$$

and

$$B(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \sin \alpha x dx.$$

How can I show formally that

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f^2(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[A^2 (\alpha) + B^2 (\alpha)]d \alpha.$$

I know that each of these are a Parseval's equality for the corresponding transforms.

Comment: What are A, B??????

Comment: @Batman I am sorry about that. I have made the proper edits to my question.